# Trailing slash must be present for .htaccess redirect 301 to take place - why?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect the following:

Redirect 301 /fruit/ https://www.website.com/vegetables/

^ The above works great IF the user clicks a link. However, should the user type-in the URL and omit the trailing slash after 'fruit' then it throws a 404.

So, my question is, how do I make all reference to /fruit/ or /fruit work correctly under 301 protocol?

Thanks for all replies

Answer (score 0):

Google was my friend: the answer is >

```
RedirectMatch 301 /fruit/?$ https://www.website.com/vegetables/
```